# How to get Map value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class clsWarehouse {

public static void main(String[] args){

    class Items {
        private String iItemID;
        private String strItemName;
        private String strItemDescription;
        private String iItemPrice;
        private String strSize;
        private String strSex;


    public Items (String id, String name, String description, String price, String size, String sex){
        iItemID = id;
        strItemName = name;
        strItemDescription = description;
        iItemPrice = price;
        strSize = size;
        strSex = sex;
        }
    }   


Map<Integer, Items> ItemMap = new HashMap<Integer, Items>();
ItemMap.put(1, new Items("3", "test1", "test2", "30", "20", "Male")); 

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Items> entry : ItemMap.entrySet()) {
System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

        Items test = entry.getValue();
        String test2 = test.toString();
        System.out.println(test2);
    }  
}
}
```

Hello,

I want to get the value stored in the map but i get only the memory locations instead, Key = 1, Value = clsWarehouse$1Items@c3c749. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Implement the `toString()` method. Please use uppercase letters to start your class names and lowercase letters for variable names.

Comment: Please note that this problem has **nothing** to do with maps. You'd have had exactly the same problem when doing e.g. `System.out.println(new Items(...))` without using any maps. I recommend to fix the question title, body and tags. By the way, "Items" is a rather poor name for an instance which concretely represents only one item. Name it "Item" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Override the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method in your `Items` class so that when you call it, you control the output.  The default implementation in `Object` produces the behavior you are observing (from the linked Javadocs)

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The `hashCode()` method, by default, [uses the memory address](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

add the getters that you need in your `Items` class

Ex (for ItemID) :

```
public String getItemID()
{
    return iItemID;
}
```

and in your `for loop`

```
Items test = entry.getValue();
System.out.println(test.getItemID());
```